# How to optimize the efficiency of results returned from paginate query in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: pagination, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Any of you guys have used Version 0.13 of Apache IoTDB to query and paginate more than 200 million time series data? Is there any method to optimize the efficiency of query result feedback? Recently, my query progress got stuck frequently, so I want to know which version or which function can I use to speed up paginate query?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade to the Version 1.1.2 or 1.2.1 of Apache IoTDB. IoTDB has implemented push-down of `limit` and `offset` executions in these versions. For this kind of pagination query, the execution speed will be greatly improved. Note that you need to use aligned time series in this case.